# Predicting values based on given data

Tags: calculus, estimation, data-analysis

```
   num  value
    8     ?
    10    ?
    12  24.33
    16  22.5
    20  22.29
    24  22.41
    28  22.55
    32    ?
    36    ?
```

let's say i have the following values.  What can I do to estimate the values for the numbers 8, 10, 32, 36?

How do i come up with a function that best represent these numbers?

I feel like i can use calculus but not exactly sure; havent used calculus in longest time

Comment: This is a really open-ended question. It is easy to interpolate values, but is that a good fit? What shape should we expect (polynomial, log, exponential, etc)?

Comment: @Fimpellizieri thats the problem. dont know. thats all the data. if i had to guess those number, i just want to know what's one way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very open-ended question, one practical way of doing this is to enter the data into Excel and add a scatter plot. Then right click on the plot and choose `Add Trendline...`

You get a choice of different fitting models. Check `Display Equation on chart` and play with different choices. Also display the $R^2$ to see the quality of fit.

In your case, as is obvious, a quadratic polynomial will fit exactly ($R^2=1$), a cubic is very close ($R^2=0.9953$) and a quadratic is slightly worse ($R^2=0.9071$),

Picturing the cubic from Excel:
[image: Excel data and graph]

You can then use the displayed equation to fit the unknown points.

Comment: based on the graph, 20 is not the mininum, correct?

Comment: @ealeon yes, but i would be somewhat suspicious using polynomial fitting for far-off extrapolation.